# how to make navigation hover using css3 just like in code42 website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am, looking for cool transitions using css3 and I am wondering on how do they make the animation everytime you hover on the navigation items on [code42](http://www.code42.com/) website, where everytime you hover, the under line button ascends to the bottom of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a pseudo-element `::after` or `::before` your menu item and animate that. I created an example here: http://codepen.io/victmo/pen/EjoPmK

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this code drops article on cool link efects..
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/06/creative-link-effects/